# Error in loading Azure Storage 2.0 -- could not load Microsoft.Data.OData 5.0.2

Tags: .net, azure, visual-studio-2012, nuget, azure-storage

My hosted service uses Azure Storage 2.0 (exactly 2.0.5.1 from Nuget). Under Visual Studio 2010 I had no problem. I switched to Visual Studio 2012 and now in some web site of my main web role I get the following exception of type `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException`:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Data.OData, Version=5.0.2.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies.
The located assembly's manifest definition does not match
the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

while Azure Storage 2.0.5.1 requires `Microsoft.Data.OData` 5.2.0.0 . The other worker roles work just fine and they seem to find the correct assembly. In every project Azure Storage 2.0 is installed from Nuget and all the references point to the `packages` folder.

I use Azure SDK 1.8 under .NET 4.0 -- this means that I also employ Azure Storage Client 1.7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a little investigation, I discovered that this web site loaded `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage` from the SDK path, the same path from which I loaded `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient` in other assemblies -- in the Modules windows in Visual Studio I can see that `iisexpress` loads the assembly with file version 2.0.0.0 . To my understanding the reference to `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient` can force Visual Studio to load `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage` from the wrong path.

After a bit of fiddling, I've moved the `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage` assembly out of SDK folder, forcing Visual Studio to reference the assembly downloaded by Nuget -- this way I had no problem.

An an alternative, I could also move `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient` to another location and change the references in my project -- but this will be quite useless since I plan to move to Azure Storage 2.0 entirely (for example, I hope that in Azure SDK 2.0 Diagnostics uses Storage 2.0).

Comment: You could also use a binding redirect which appears to be what the library attempts to do anyway.

Comment: @PhilCooper right observation. I would usually prefer to track down the cause of the assembly loading problem, since it can hide some "fundamental" problems (for example, in this case assemblies loaded from the wrong path), and only as last resort (when I cannot find the cause of the problem) use an assembly redirect.